# Is there a potential estoppel issue here?

Tags: prosecution, estoppel

Patent A is granted. Patent application B is related to A, but is a new application. Patent A is prior art to Patent application B. To prosecute Patent application B to grant, can an attorney make a submission of some sort of deficiency in granted Patent A without creating an issue of estoppel in Patent A?

Comment: Is patent B an improvement on patent A? Is patent A and B owned by the same entity?

Comment: What do you think is gained by pointing out a deficiency in A?  And what sort of estoppel to you think can occur? I suggest not using technical legal terms unless used with a good background but rather spelling out your concern in relatively lay terms.